# Can we run Confluent JDBC Kafka connector in Windows Operating system?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

we are planning to install and run Confluent's JDBC connector in the Windows Operating System(without Docker and Cygwin with curl installed).

I found a couple of posts saying, we need some "pre-requisite" and
"Confluent Platform is not supported on Windows OS".

is this still the same with Confluent Platform  5.0 version as well?

What is the best way to run Confluent's JDBC connector in Windows OS?

Comment: At the end of the day, it's all Java, and is expected to run on all OS's that Java runs on. Confluent Platform is only not extensively tested in producution environments on Windows machines

Comment: If it is not extensively tested and not widely used, then it is very risky to recommend for the production environment.

Comment: I've not seen anywhere documented that running Kafka or Connectors are recommended to be ran on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confluent Platform is not supported on Windows. Your best way to run it is under Docker. If you're using Docker, you can easily deploy the JDBC connector on Windows.

But, technically kafka-connect-jdbc is just a JAR plugin to Kafka Connect, which is part of Apache Kafka - so give it a go and report back if it works ;)

Comment: it has released windows paths, the only issue is when you download it, the jdbc connectors aren't configure, it is default these ones :    ElasticsearchSinkConnector/ S3SinkConnector/ SchemaSourceConnector/ FileStreamSinkConnector/ FileStreamSourceConnector